# Jar is working in terminal and not working when running thought intellij run

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ keeps throwing same runtime error, although jar runs correctly in terminal.

I suspect that jar is also being cached.

How to make sure IntelliJ runs latest built artifact(jar)?

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post the full error stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
gradlew --no-build-cache clean assembleDebug
```

If not, clean the folder from `.gradle/caches`